# Using SPFx solutions styling in the SharePoint App

Tags: sharepoint, spfx, sharepoint-apps

For those of you using SharePoint Framework solutions, how are you handling and approaching the different user experiences of the SharePoint App vs the mobile browser? Particularly for custom navigation elements in application customizers / extensions?

The biggest hurtle is custom styles for mobile navigation. In the SharePoint app, the site header experience and style is much different than the mobile browser. Are UserAgents -> "(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad')"the way to go? Even so, is there a UserAgenet specified for the mobile SharePoint app?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9g8ad.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that you can handle this is Responsive Layout: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/styles/layout

All other things SPO does for you.